# How class definition works?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was just looking into higher component in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html), but I found the code like below:

```
return class extends React.Component {
// no name ^ ^ here
```

Is this a typo? If not, can you please point out how class definition works here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [class expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/class).

It doesn't need a name because it is being handled by the code on its LHS (i.e. the `return`).

Comment: Thanks for the term class expression. I was not finding it.

Comment: Further, I was confused because I have used class with the name when combined with extends keyword. I found myself a dumb because I know `class {}` earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Classes in JavaScript can be anonymous just like functions.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/class

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not a typo, it is called [class expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/class).The class expression is one way to define a class in ECMAScript 2015. Similar to function expressions, class expressions can be named or unnamed. If named, the name of the class is local to the class body only. JavaScript classes use prototype-based inheritance. The signature to define class expression is:

```
var MyClass = class [className] [extends] {
  // class body
};
```